# Can we define constructors for a GUI-designed Agent?

Tags: anylogic

I created a GUI-designed Agent MyBatch. I would like to know if it is possible to define a constructor for this agent.

More specifically, I would need it in `fluidToAgent`, where I would like the new Agent to be the type of MyBatch.

However,

```
New agent = new MyBatch()
```

gives me an 'empty' MyBatch, where I would like have something along the lines of

```
New agent = new MyBatch(batch.variable_1, batch.variable_2, etc...)
```

so that I can initialize New agent with data contained in the current batch

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to add parameters to your GUI constructed agent.  Then

```
new agent = new MyBatch( param1, param2...)
```

You can go to the agents properties window to see which order the parameters should be passed in.  This get the parameters passed in and set, and then you can use OnStartUp action to perform any logic you would like.

One important item to note is that if you create an AnyLogic agent via new MyBatch().. you must also call **createAndStart( anyAgent )** to initialize any objects on the canvas.

If you use a population of MyBatch, and then use

```
new agent = add_populationMyBatch( param1, param2, ...)
```

you do not have to worry about calling createAndStart

Another alternative is to have you own initialization function within MyBatch.  You can create the agent via new agent = new MyBatch() and then call agent.init( variables passed in ).  Within init you can call createAndStart and whatever other code you would like.